# OpenLayers with Google, Bing & MapQuest - Does it violate the terms of service?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, bing-maps

to my understanding, you are not allowed to use the Google Maps API to display Google and Bing maps (Layer Toggle) (From the terms of service). However, I'm unclear if I can have an OpenLayers map that allows the users to switch between Google, Bing and MapQuest. I want to let the user be able to choose the best Satellite/Aerial data available for their location. I'm really unclear if this is a Terms Of Service violation.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nick,

Comment: Map tile access is different than using say geocoding components with need to be used in conjunction with the same service/tiles provider. Most cases you are allowed - though we are not lawyers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a lawyer. But i think it's okay. I've done it for years now on several implementations and this is the first time I've ever heard of this concern. As long as you have the "Powered by Google" when you're on the google layer and follow the rest of their terms such as not charging people to access that layer, then you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok since you're not using the Google API to display Bing Tiles.  You're using OpenLayers to switch between various map providers.  Just don't remove the logo with CSS and you should be fine.

Note that your application has to be publicly accessible (or fit a few other categories to be free).  Otherwise, if it's behind a login, you have to pony up for a real licenese.  That goes for any of the map providers.